# How to create read-only property

Tags: powershell

When I run this code it results in $o having a Name property with no value, even though I passed 'MyObj' as the name.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

```
function CreateSomething {
    param( [string] $name )

    $o = new-object PSObject
    write-host '$name:' $name
    $o | add-member -name Name -passThru -force -memberType ScriptProperty -value { $name }
   $o
}

$o = CreateSomething -name MyObj
$o
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve here?

The `-value { $name }` will be the scriptblock that is used for the ScriptProperty and it has no idea of `$name` ( it is not in scope)

You can do it this way:

```
$o | add-member -name Name -passThru -force -memberType ScriptProperty -value { $name }.GetNewClosure()
```

I don't see why you can't just do:

```
$o | add-member -name Name -passThru -force -memberType NoteProperty -value $name
```

Note: Since you are using `-passThru` in the above statement, you can omit the lone `$o` in the last line of your function.

Comment: I was hoping to create a read-only property named 'Name' that returns 'MyObj'.  If I use NoteProperty would it be read/write?

Comment: @bddogcatball - I have given a `ScriptProperty` alternative too

Comment: Aha!  Your ScriptProperty alternative with GetNewClosure() worked.  I changed the title of my post to reflect what I actually wanted to achieve.

Comment: GetNewClosure() was just what I needed. Thanks!